# Which is faster, PRF based on AES-CTR and PRF based on BLAKE{2,3}?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, blake3

Recently Blake3 has been announced, which can be used as PRF.
I'm wondering which PRF is faster, namely PRF based on Blake3 or the one based on AES-CTR?

Comment: About what platform(s) are we talking about here? About how much data are we talking? Is the key largely fixed or often-changing? Also intuitively Blake3 should be slower because it's designed to be a collision-resistant hash (which cannot be built from OWFs) whereas AES-CTR is "just" an encryption scheme (which can be built from OWFs so is "easier" in principle).

Answer (score 2):

As @SEJPM pointed out above, there's no one answer to this question. Everything varies based on what hardware you've got and what the length of your input is. As a first step, I'd start by looking at SUPERCOP performance measurements. You can find AES-CTR measurements at https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-stream.html, and BLAKE3 measurements at https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-hash.html. There's an enormous amount of data in both pages, because there's a lot of different hardware to consider. (And of course, lots of stream ciphers and hash functions to measure.)